# Best practice to update or get ranks of players in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've been starting a project where multiple players are in multiple leagues. They get points and in the end there is a ranking-table which displays the player with the most points.

So far so good, but I've got a problem getting the ranking of the players correctly.

The competitors I getting like that because competitors can be teams or players (of course teams OR players per league, not both in one league):

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'competitors', 'league_id', 'competitors_id')
        ->where('competitors.competitors_type', 'App\User')
        ->withPivot('id', 'points', 'wins', 'lose', 'score', 'enemy_score')->withTimestamps();
```

I tried adding following method to the pivot-table-model `Competitor`:

```php
public function getRankAttribute()
{
    return $this->league->competitors()->where('points', '>=', $this->points)->count();
}
```

But the problem with this logic is, that I want to add more logic to the ranking like: Player A has same amount of points like Player B. But Player B is better than Player A because he has more wins.

Next I tried to give a rank in the query after multiple `orderBy`:

```php
    // $ranking is a relation or Eloquent Builder instance
    // which has already got multiple orderBy() statements.
    $query = null;
    $baseQuery = null;

    if($ranking instanceof Relation) {
        $query = $ranking->getQuery();
        $baseQuery = $ranking->getBaseQuery();
    } else {
        $query = $ranking;
        $baseQuery = $ranking->getQuery();
    }

    // Set the rank offset
    $offset = (int) $baseQuery->offset;
    DB::statement(DB::raw("set @rank={$offset}"));

    // Adjust SELECT clause to contain the rank
    if ( ! count($baseQuery->columns)) $query->select($columns);
    $query->addSelect([DB::raw('@rank:=@rank+1 as rank')]);

    // Return the object again
    return $ranking;
```

This doesn't work as well, because the sorting is done AFTER the rank was given to the entry. So I get the increasing number of the row but not the rank. In my example the last player which joins the league gets the highest "rank".

Now I'm thinking of a scheduled task which will update the ranks of the players every 5 minutes or so. But is this really best practice? What do you think? How should I do this?

I'm using a MYSQL database and Laravel 5.2

Comment: It might be worth adding a method to the `League` model instead that constructs the SQL query to rank players based on their points, and then cache _that_ result.

Comment: I updated the question. And how would you cache that result? And how long? Who would fill that cache? The user which loads the page or an cronjob/task?

Comment: I would go with the cronjob using the scheduled commands from Laravel